# Add values of elements in array using javascript with out using const

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had an array with

```
    0:{Name: "Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:200}
    1:{Name: "Test2",Cost:100,Revenue:100}
    2:{Name: "Test3",Cost:100,Revenue:300}
    3:{Name: "Test2",Cost:200,Revenue:100}
    4:{Name: "Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:300}
    5:{Name: "Test4",Cost:100,Revenue:300}
```

I am expecting result with out duplicates based on names and other values (cost and revenue) as added

```
0:{Name: "Test1",Cost:200,Revenue:500}
1:{Name: "Test2",Cost:300,Revenue:200}
2:{Name: "Test3",Cost:100,Revenue:300}
3:{Name: "Test4",Cost:100,Revenue:300}
```

I am trying with below code

```
var removeDuplicates = function(originalArray, prop) {
    var newArray = [];
    var lookupObject  = {};
    for(var i in originalArray) {
        lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
    }

    for(i in lookupObject) {
        newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
console.log('Name array ',removeDuplicates(tempRoleMap, 'Name'));
```

Can you help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to iterate over the array while assigning to an accumulator object indexed by `Name`. On each array item, either assign it as the new object at that key in the accumulator if it doesn't exist yet, or iterate over the item's `entries` (other than `Name`) and add to the appropriate property in the accumulator.

At the end, you'll have an object indexed by `Name`s, so to get the array out of the object, call `Object.values` on it:

```js
const arr=[{Name:"Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:200},{Name:"Test2",Cost:100,Revenue:100},{Name:"Test3",Cost:100,Revenue:300},{Name:"Test2",Cost:200,Revenue:100},{Name:"Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:300},{Name:"Test4",Cost:100,Revenue:300}]

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, { Name, ...rest }) => {
  if (!a[Name]) a[Name] = { Name, ...rest };
  else {
    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      a[Name][key] += val;
    });
  }
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```

It's best to use ES6+ when writing code, and then you can transpile it down to ES5 automatically with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and polyfills. But, if you *had* to write in ES5, then:

```js
var arr=[{Name:"Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:200},{Name:"Test2",Cost:100,Revenue:100},{Name:"Test3",Cost:100,Revenue:300},{Name:"Test2",Cost:200,Revenue:100},{Name:"Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:300},{Name:"Test4",Cost:100,Revenue:300}]

var obj = arr.reduce(function(a, item) {
  var Name = item.Name;
  if (!a[Name]) a[Name] = item;
  else {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
      if (key === 'Name') return;
      a[Name][key] += item[key];
    });
  }
  return a;
}, {});
var output = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  output.push(obj[key]);
});
console.log(output);
```

As you can see, it's a whole lot wordier and inelegant - better to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, and transpile down to your target environment *automatically* later.

Comment: I cannot use const , const is not allowed in my code

Comment: let it be 'var' then

Comment: @Gajini Ok, editing... you should mention something like that *before* people start posting answers

Answer (score -1):

You can get the desired output using `.reduce()` and `Object.values()`:

```js
let data = [
    {Name: "Test1", Cost:100, Revenue:200},
    {Name: "Test2", Cost:100, Revenue:100},
    {Name: "Test3", Cost:100, Revenue:300},
    {Name: "Test2", Cost:200, Revenue:100},
    {Name: "Test1", Cost:100, Revenue:300},
    {Name: "Test4", Cost:100, Revenue:300}
];

let result = Object.values(
    data.reduce((r, c) => {
        r[c.Name] = r[c.Name] || {};
        r[c.Name].Cost = (r[c.Name].Cost || 0) + c.Cost;
        r[c.Name].Revenue = (r[c.Name].Revenue || 0) + c.Revenue;
        return r;
    }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You will find a solution in the snippet below:

```js
var arr = [{Name: "Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:200},
    {Name: "Test2",Cost:100,Revenue:100},
    {Name: "Test3",Cost:100,Revenue:300},
    {Name: "Test2",Cost:200,Revenue:100},
    {Name: "Test1",Cost:100,Revenue:300},
    {Name: "Test4",Cost:100,Revenue:300}];
    
    
    function removeDuplicates(arr, prop){
      arr.forEach((a, i) => arr.slice(i+1).filter(e => e[prop] == a[prop]).forEach( el => {  
        if (arr.indexOf(el) > -1) 
          arr.splice(arr.indexOf(el), 1); 
      }));
      
      return arr;
    }

console.log(removeDuplicates(arr, 'Name'));
```